# SQL Server Management Studio 2016

Tags: sql-server, ssms

I'm having a strange problem with my SSMS 2016. Within the query window `backspace`, `del`, `up`, `down`, `left`, `right` keys have stopped working. When I reset my environment settings with "Import and Export Settings" to default setting it works but the changes don't persist when I exit the SSMS client. Every time I launch SSMS 2016 I have to do this exercise.

I also have SSMS 2014 on the same system, which works with out any problem, I tried to uninstall and install the SSMS 16 client but no luck.

Any one having the same problem?

Help please, how can I uninstall SQL Server Management Studio 2016 completely?

Comment: Also remember the settings are with Visual Studio since SSMS is now using the VS fully. So times where I install any VS 2015 update my settings in SSMS 2016 will get reset. I have not tried since the October release of SSMS though, so they may have fixed it.

Comment: What build of SSMS do you have installed? As well, when you are resetting what collection are you picking to reset (default option is to SQL Server 2008 R2)?

Comment: What language version of the OS are you running and what language version of SQL Server Management Studio 16 are you using?

Comment: possible related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/484248/visual-studio-appears-to-randomly-adopt-american-keyboard-layout

Answer (score 4):

This happened in SSMS 2017.  There was a pop-under "Add table to view" dialog that I didn't know about. 
When I went to close SSMS it warned me about the dialog (which I could not close/cancel), then gave me an ugly exception about protected memory.
After restarting SSMS it all worked again.

Answer (score 3):

This is an old question, but I fell prey to this issue recently and found that SSMS wasn't overwriting a "bad" settings file.  To fix it, I had to close SSMS and simply delete the settings file using Windows Explorer.  SSMS then loaded with the default settings when I started it back up and I was able to reset things to the way I wanted once more without issue.  I suspect something occurred on the network that prevented SSMS from overwriting the old file (as my path is mapped to a UNC copy of the My Documents folder).

The settings file location can be found within SSMS at **Tools** → **Options** → ***Environment*** → ***Import and Export Settings***

[image]

Hopefully this helps someone else in the future.